# why does a device on the network seem to always have the same ip upon reboot, even though they're dhcp?

Tags: dhcp

It's not 100%, but pretty much all of my devices are assigned the same ip address upon reboot. I am at a lost to explain why.

Do you know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a DHCP server offers an IP address to a requesting device, the IP address comes with a "lease": a length of time for which it is valid. If the same device (ie same MAC address) does another request in that time period, it will get the same reply. If you turn off or reboot a device the DHCP server doesn't know that.

If the requesting device is still powered on when the lease expires, it is supposed to request another IP address, though I suspect many devices don't! (Leases typically last a long time.)

DHCP servers though may well issue the same IP address to a device even after the lease has expired, but they will always have a (possibly configurable) timeout value for this too or their internal device vs. IP table would grow indefinitely.

Even if the requesting device has been forgotten by the DHCP server it might still get the same IP address eg if the server's algorithm allocates the lowest unallocated IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that DHCP clients would request the same IP address that they were using prior to the reboot. You might notice that in the DHCP request's option field if you capture the DHCP requests made by the clients.

For more info please check this YouTube Video:

https://youtu.be/Cy0M54GSpBg

[DHCP CAPTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUOXs.png)